# How to use .js file components in routes for a router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have just started learning VueJS and I got stuck on how to use components in routes for a router.

I have a component:

```
export default Home = {
  template: `
    <div class="top_container">
        <div class="left_container">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>Current Settings</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="inner_container">
                <p>URL: <span><?php if(isset($arrayInputs[0])) echo $arrayInputs[0]; ?></span></p>
                <p>URL Refresh Interval: <span><?php if(isset($arrayInputs[1])) echo $arrayInputs[1]; ?></span>(s)</p>
                <p>Brightness: <span><?php if(isset($arrayInputs[2])) echo $arrayInputs[2]; ?></span>(&#37;)</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="right_container">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>Change Settings</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="inner_container">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    `,
};
```

I have the main app:

```
import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js";
import "https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js";

import "./components/Navbar.js";
import Home from "./components/Home.js";

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', redirect: '/home' },
    { path: '/home', component: Home },
    // { path: '/dhcp', component: DHCP },
    // { path: '/static', component: Static },
    // { path: '/update', component: Update },
    { path: '*', component: NotFound }
  ]
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: router,
})
```

and I have the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script type="module" src="./src/App.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        <section>
            <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
                <router-view></router-view>
            </transition>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and the error:

```
Home.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Home is not defined
```

**What am I doing wrong ?**

I know that to create a html element from a component I can use:

```
Vue.component("Home", { ... });
```

just like I did with `<Navbar></Navbar>`, but I need to use them in `routes` as components not as html tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reference error comes from the word `Home` in the first line of `Home.js`. Start the Home component like this:

```
export default {
    name: "Home",
    ...
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

export default Home = {

remove the Home should work for you..
what i wrote above is how you write a separate routes.js file and the best practice for writing routes and importing components